# How to determine the Differential Equation from the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a system that has a theoretical basis to behave according to the following:

$$\left[\begin{array}{}\dot{T}_1\\\dot{T}_2\end{array}\right]=A\left[\begin{array}{}T_1\\T_2\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{}k_1\cdot q\\k_2\cdot T_3\end{array}\right]$$

This system represents a thermal transient

The variables $T_1$, and $T_3$ can be measured.  $T_2$ cannot easily be measured and no date for this temperature is available.  They were once a minute for a period of 300 minutes.  The transient follows turning the equipment on, so the value for $q$ step changes from 0 to what can be assumed to be a constant value of about 10W. I used a Levenberg–Marquardt to regress the data, and determined it to have the following transient for one set of initial conditions.

$$T_1-T_3=42^{\circ}C-10.0866^{\circ}C e^{\frac{-t}{167.9077}}-24.2457^{\circ}C e^{\frac{-t}{6.1154}}$$

This equation fits the data very well ($R^2=0.9967$).

There is also a theoretical basis that when the equipment was turned on (at a time before $t=0$), $T_1=T_2=T_3$.  Also, $a_{11}=-a_{12}$, and $a_{21}=k_2$

I want to be able to model the system with any arbitrary set of initial conditions.  Is there a way with the available information to solve for the $A$ matrix and for $k_2$ and $k_1\cdot q$?  If not, is there a good way to model the $T_1$ transient if $T_1-T_3$ were to start at an arbitrary specified initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have the model system
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} T_1}{\text{d} t} &= a_{11}(T_1 - T_2) + k_1 q(t), \tag{1a}\\
 \frac{\text{d} T_2}{\text{d} t} &= k_2 T_1 + a_{22} T_2 + k_2 T_3(t).\tag{1b}
\end{align}
Moreover, you can measure $T_1$ and $T_3$, and you control $q(t)$. In other words, these three functions are known for all time $t$ -- at least for a large number of time points.

You can use $(1a)$ to express $T_2$ in terms of the other functions, yielding
\begin{equation}
T_2 = \frac{k_1 q-\frac{\text{d}T_1}{\text{d} t}}{a_{11}}+T_1. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now you can substitute $(2)$ in $(1b)$ to obtain the relation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{k_1 \frac{\text{d} q}{\text{d} t} - a_{22} k_1 q(t) + a_{22} \frac{\text{d} T_1}{\text{d} t} - \frac{\text{d}^2 T_1}{\text{d} t^2}}{a_{11}} - (a_{22} + k_2) T_1 - k_2 T_3 + \frac{\text{d} T_1}{\text{d} t} = 0. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Note that $(3)$ holds *identically*, i.e. for all $t$. Therefore, you can use the function values of $T_1$, $T_3$ and $q$ at all measure times $t_i$, $0\leq i\leq300$, together with the (finite time approximation of) the first and second time derivative of $T_1$, to obtain a system of $300$ equations of the form $(3)$ with $T_1 \to T_1(t_i)$, $T_3 \to T_3(t_i)$, etc. for your four unknown parameters $(k_1,k_2,a_{11},a_{22})$. There are good numerical methods to find the best solution to this overdetermined linear system.

Comment: One concern: how to interpret $\frac{dq}{dt}$ if $q$ is actually not differentiable?

Comment: Assuming that the instant of measuring does not coincide with the increase of $q$, I believe you can assume that $q$ is constant during measurement, which would simplify $(3)$ somewhat.